# Mongoose - Define Multiple Data Types for the same field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following mongoose model defined:

```
     responseMessage: {
        type: String,
        required: false
     }
```

I want this field to accept either String or Array values. How can I do this?

Comment: Mixed? {https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed}

Comment: @AlexZeDim can you please tell me how I can implement Mixed in the above Schema?

Comment: @TonyMathew did you ever find a solution for this? I am wanting to do the same.